# Problem with Nvidia after update

Tags: boot, nvidia, updates, graphics

After adding the most recent set of updates, I can't get into Ubuntu at all. I get a screen saying that I am running in low-graphics mode, 'your screen, graphics card and input device settings could not be detected correctly etc'.

I can hit return and then get to the next screen saying 'what would you like to do?' however, i can't choose from the 4 options, the only keystroke that will register is escape, which takes me to a black screen with a login.

I have an Nvidia GeForce 7050/nForce 610i and it has caused problems in the past, but I have always got round it by choosing to boot in recovery mode. Now, no matter which version I try to boot into I can't get into Ubuntu at all.

Answer (score 0):

Open virtual terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> in the screen shows `running in low graphics mode`.Login with your username and password.

Then run the below commands,

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Poweron your pc, I hope it works.

Comment: unfortunately, no improvement on the situation - no change at all. There are two other xorg.conf files - xorg.conf.failsafe and xorg.conf.dist-upgrade-201211122052 are either of these likely to be a problem too?